# Remove duplicate values from hashtables

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am new with powershell and i need to remove duplicate values from my hashtable, eg `"c"` has a duplicate 3 - `"3,4,3"` and `"d"` has duplicate 1 - `"1,1,6,4"`.

```
[hashtable]$alpha = @{
"a" = "1";
"b" = "2,1,5";
"c" = "3,4,3";
"d" = "1,1,6,4";
"e" = "1,7,9,0";
}
```

How can I get the result?

I have already tried `select-object -unique` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, Those are strings, split them first and rejoin after:

```
$NewAlpha = $Alpha.GetEnumerator() |% { $_.value = ($_.value -split "," | select -unique) -join "," ; $_}
```

Note: this does not preserve the [hashtable] type.
To do that you will need to employ the approach mentioned in the answer provided by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

```
@($alpha.Keys) |% {$alpha.$_ = ($alpha.$_ -split ',' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ','}
```

Comment: The core of your answer - the value-transformation part - is sound, but you're not creating a new _hashtable_, you're creating an _array of `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]` instances_.
This may not be obvious if you output `$NewAlpha` to the console, but  `$NewAlpha.GetType().FullName` and `$NewAlpha[0].GetType().fullname` will tell you.
As an aside: The OP's use case doesn't require creating  a _new_ hashtable.

Comment: Good catch about the output type. That is true.

Answer (score 6):

In order **to use `Select-Object -Unique`, your values must be in a *collection* (array)**, not inside a single string.

Thus, you must first split the string into an array of tokens (`-split` operator), and afterwards reassemble the distinct tokens into a string (`-join` operator).

```
foreach ($key in @($alpha.Keys)) {
  $alpha.$key = ($alpha.$key -split ',' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ','
}
```

Note the `@(...)` around `$alpha.Keys`, which effectively *clones* the keys collection, which is necessary because you'd otherwise get an error due to trying to modify the collection while it is being enumerated, which is not supported.
In **PSv3+** you could use `$alpha.Keys.Clone()` instead, which is more efficient.

You could also use the *pipeline* with a call to the `ForEach-Object` (`%`) *cmdlet* (rather than an *expression* with the `foreach` *loop*), but **for in-memory data structures a `foreach` *loop* is generally the better and faster choice**.

For the sake of completeness, here's the pipeline solution (tip of the that to [WayneA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51502700/45375) for refining it):

```
@($alpha.Keys) | ForEach-Object { 
  $alpha[$_] = ($alpha[$_.] -split ',' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ',' 
}
```

<sup>Note that `@(...)` is still needed around `$alpha.Keys`, as in the `foreach` statement solution.</sup>

As in the `foreach` solution, this modifies the hashtable in place.

Another option is to use **`$alpha.GetEnumerator()`** in order to force PowerShell to send the hashtable's *entries* one by one through the pipeline, as `[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]` instances representing key-value pairs with a `.Key` and a `.Value` property - by default, PowerShell outputs hashtables *as a whole*.

However, that **necessitates creating a *new* hashtable**, because **you fundamentally cannot modify a collection being enumerated with `.GetEnumerator()` (as is also implicitly used by a `foreach` loop)**.

```
$newAlpha = @{} # initialize the new hash table
$alpha.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { 
  $newAlpha[$_.Key] = ($alpha[$_.Key] -split ',' | Select-Object -Unique) -join ',' 
}
# $newAlpha now contains the updated entries.
```